# How to create a jax array and store dictionaries inside it later?

Tags: python, jax

I wish to create a Jax-based array and use this array later to store dictionaries inside it. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAX arrays cannot store dictionaries as items. They can only store items of simple numerical types, including:

- integers: `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`
- unsigned integers: `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`
- floating point: `bfloat16`, `float16`, `float32`, `float64`
- complex; `complex64`, `complex128`

Additionally, several experimental narrow-width float and integer types from the [ml_dtypes](https://github.com/jax-ml/ml_dtypes) library have support on some hardware.

Depending on your use-case, you may be able to use a struct-of-arrays pattern rather than an array-of-structs pattern, but it's hard to say whether this is applicable without more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I want to store the dictionaries containing the parameters for Bayesian inference. These dictionaries containing parameters are generated during jax.lax.scan loop. Thus, I wish to pass this array (some data type to store those dictionaries produced) in the jax.lax.scan and store the results obtained. Hope that provides more clarity to my question. It would be great if you could please provide a solution specific to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like rather than using an array containing dicts of parameters, you should use a dict containing arrays of parameters.

Comment: I am trying to modify an existing code base. I cannot change the output of the dict to array :(